# Функция реверсирования элементов массива первого и последнего столбцов

Tags: c, массивы

У меня есть масив с размером Н и М. Нужно первый и последний столбец перевернуть. Как я могу ето сделать. Спасибо за ответ.
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Двумерный массив в Си, грубо (очень) говоря - таблица (матрица, как хотите называйте). Итак двумерный массив выглядит:

```
1 2 3 - строка   
4 5 6
7 8 9
|
столбец
```

Двумерый массив выглядит вот так : *название_массива[номер столбца][номер строки]* (`int a[3][3]`), нумерация идёт от 0; на пример чтобы обратиться к 6-ке вы могли бы написать `a[1][2]`.

То есть, чтобы решить ваши задачу вам необходимо в первом цикле пробежаться по элементам от `a[0][0]` до `a[0][n-1]`, где n - кол-во строк, а во втором по элементам от `a[m][0]` до `a[m][n-1]`, где m - кол-во столбцов. В первом цикле берёте a[0][i] меняете местом с `a[0][n-1-i]` (пример, i = 1 : `a[0][1]` <-> `a[0][n-2]` и т.д.)

З.Ы. Вообще это элементарные вещи и их нужно искать самому в интернете куча примеров и вы никогда не научитесь программировать, если не будете искать ответы на подобные вопросы!